# How to check if mouse is still over element in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to write to the console is the user is keeping the mouse over an element for more than 2 seconds, this is the code:

```
var $els = document.querySelectorAll('#myDiv');
    for(i = 0; i < $els.length; i++) {
        if ($($els[i]).data('track') == 'hover') {
            $els[i].addEventListener('mouseover', function (e) {
                setTimeout(function() {
                    if ($($els[i]).is(':hover')) {
                        console.log('mouse is still over this element');
                    }
                }, 2000);
            });
        }
    }
```

the message is written to the console after 2 seconds, even if I keep the mouse on the element less than 2 seconds. I am probably missing something in here:

```
if ($($els[i]).is(':hover')) {
```

thanks for your help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to have a mouseover event fire only if the mouse is hovered over an element for at least 1 second?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6231052/how-to-have-a-mouseover-event-fire-only-if-the-mouse-is-hovered-over-an-element)

Comment: [this might help you](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1670561/6139043)

Comment: I wonder that it works at all. because `i` inside your event listener will be `$els.length` at the time the event is fired.

Comment: Your `setTimeout` will fire after 2 secs!

Comment: Are you sure the script is using the expected element for checking :hover-status?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Edit : I updated my previous answer with a better solution.*

First, you propably have several elements with the same id and it's a bad things, so I changed to a class. Then I updated your code to simplify it and to make it more in the spirit of jQuery :

HTML :

```
<div class="myDiv" data-track='hover'>
test
</div>
<div class="myDiv" data-track='hover'>
test2
</div>
```

JavaScript :

```
$('.myDiv[data-track=hover]').on("mouseenter",function(){
    var $elem = $(this);
  $elem.attr("data-hover",true);
  window.setTimeout(function() {
    if ($elem.attr("data-hover")) {
        console.log('mouse is still over this element');
        console.log($elem);
    }
  }, 2000);
})

$('.myDiv[data-track=hover]').on("mouseenter",function(){
  $(this).attr("data-hover",false);
});
```

Here is a working [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nfx00ygw/7/).

Comment: how can I refer to my over element inside if(hover[1]) { ?

Comment: I think $els[i] should work or you can add a parameter in the function().

Comment: maybe I marked this as correct too early, sorry. looks like it is not checking the correct element. if you check console.log(i + ':' + hover[1]); i is always the first element...

Comment: try to add i as a parameter then :

setTimeout(function(i) {
                    if (hover[i]) {
                        console.log('mouse is still over this element');
                    }
                }, 2000);

Comment: not sure how, can you update the answer above to show me please?

Comment: Done, I simply added the i on the function().

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141551/discussion-between-user3174311-and-nico).

Comment: Yes sorry, I didn't put the link of the good version : https://jsfiddle.net/nfx00ygw/7/ it's fixed thanks.

Comment: I just tried on Chrome (73.0.3683.46) and it still works, I see the log in the console. Can you be more precise on what is not working @SpencerO'Reilly

Comment: It console logs even if you are not still hovering over the element. I ended up using something like this https://stackoverflow.com/a/6231142/4059832

Answer (score 18):

Create a global variable as

`var isMouseHover = false;`

Call function on the mouseover call [**mouseover**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/Events/mouseover) function and set

`isMouseHover = true;`

And call [**mouseout**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/mouseout), when mouse out and set

`isMouseHover = false;`

Use this `isMouseHover` variable whenever you want.

Try this:

```js
let isMouseHover = false
let test = document.getElementById("test");
test.addEventListener("mouseleave", function (event) {
  isMouseHover = false
  event.target.textContent = "mouse out"
  console.log(isMouseHover)
}, false);
test.addEventListener("mouseover", function (event) {
  isMouseHover = true
  event.target.textContent = "mouse in"
  console.log(isMouseHover)
}, false);
```

```html
  <div id="test">hover me</div>
```

Comment: this is very good and straight forward strategy to get the job done!

Comment: `mouseleave` (or `mouseout`) may be not triggered if something overlay element before you leave with cursor. Manually checking `:hover` may be good idea

Answer (score 12):

A much simpler solution is available on all modern browsers.

```
var element = document.querySelector('#myElement');

if (element.matches(':hover')) {
    console.log('Mouse is over the element now.');
}
```

Comment: So smart and simple, love it

Comment: more robust. As @l00k mentioned if you put an overlay over the element in question mouse out doesn't always trigger