# How to create mouseover info popup (Like mouseover on the picture of user in facebook)

Tags: html, css

I want the user information to popup like on Facebook. See the picture below for an example of the issue. Thanks!
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1KXRQk-arf256KakeGB-lCSkX0DsAt5wq

Comment: Hello Eagle, congrats for your first post in stackoverflow. Well, for most of our coding questions, you will find that it was already asked and solved before. It is mainly about using the right keywords in searching to find an answer. You may review threads like these that are similar to your quest: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4944550/show-popup-if-the-mouse-is-hovered-over-an-element-for-a-period-of-time
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27004136/position-popup-image-on-mouseover

Answer (score 2):

HTML:

```
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit ames
        </div>
        <div class="popUp">
            ames dolor sit amen.
        </div>
    </div>
```

CSS

```
    .wrapper {
    position: relative;
    }

    .wrapper:hover > .popUp {
    display: block;
    }

    .popUp {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background: green;
    color: white;
    left: 120px;
    padding: 32px;
    }
```